# Create dynamic dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a Repeater control in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704847/create-a-repeater-control-in-asp-net)

I would like to create a dynamic drop down when i click a button. In Default, a drop down list show with list item.then i click the add new button means the next drop down create under the first one and so on...

Comment: I think you can find aswer in the pretty same question asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704847/create-a-repeater-control-in-asp-net  ... By you

Comment: can you add some more description to your question? What is the default list item in drop down? Should the default list item have "Add new" text? So when you select "Add new" from the first dropdownlist, it create a second drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in the button click event...

```
DropDownList d = new DropDownList();
 d.Items.Add("Select");
 Panel1.Controls.Add(d);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.The above code create a single dropdownlist only. But i need no of dropdown when i click no of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = "ID";
    ddl.DataSource = data;
    ddl.DataTextField = "TextFieldName";
    ddl.DataValueField = "ValueFieldName";
    form1.Controls.Add(ddl);
    form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.The above code create a single dropdownlist only. But i need no of dropdown when i click no of clicks.